# Psycopg2 - multiple hosts for a PGSQL database

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

Does anyone know if it's currently possible to have multiple hosts and ports in psycopg2 connection string for PostgreSQL databases?

`postgresql+psycopg2://<username>:<password>@host.domain.name/database` is what I have - is it possible to specify multiple hosts if I have primary/secondary setup for failovers?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to an incorrect documentation.

1. [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#specifying-multiple-fallback-hosts) link suggests that using `psycopg2` I have to specify the format as
   `username:password@/database?host=name1:port&host=name2&host=name3`
2. The above will always give error, and also will not fall back on alternative hosts. It will take a random host on the list. You need to provide `target_session_attrs` parameter as per [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html)   documentation
3. So the correct way (at least one option) is to use the below format
   `postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@/<db_name>?host=<primary_db_host>&host=<secondary_db_host>&port=<port_no>&target_session_attrs=primary`

Please note (I didn't test these)

1. It might not work if you have primary/secondary hosts running off of different ports
2. Since I am using psycopg2 through SQLAlchemy, I only tried this format, but other format might work too

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks like you are using SQLAlchemy. I do not have that set up but I can show the`psycopg2` portion. In this case Postgres 14 is listening on port `5432` and Postgres 12 on `5442`:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432,localhost:5442/test")
cur = con.cursor()  
cur.execute("select version()")
cur.fetchone()                                                                                                                                                            
('PostgreSQL 14.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0, 64-bit',)

--sudo systemctl stop postgres14

con = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432,localhost:5442/test")
cur = con.cursor()  
cur.execute("select version()")
cur.fetchone()                      
('PostgreSQL 12.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0, 64-bit',)
```

For more information see [libpq connection string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING), in particular *34.1.1.3. Specifying Multiple Hosts* and the paragraph just above it. It will not automatically fail over.